Is there a way in R to subset or fragment lubridate interval objects to count the days in subsetted intervals?
Dear Stackoverflow Community,
I'm currently working with a dataset that contains start and end dates for individual travelers. However, I'm only interested in measuring the duration of time in days that the travelers spent at a location between a given set of days.
For example:
library(lubridate)
traveler1_startdate <- mdy("3/11/2020")
traveler1_enddate <- mdy("7/1/2023")

Instead of:
length_stay <- traveler1_endate - traveler1_startdate

I'd like to know the total number of days the traveler stayed in the location between these dates:
5/1/2020 - 9/1/2020, 5/1/2021 - 9/1/2021, 5/1/2022 - 9/1/2022, 5/1/2023 - 9/1/2023
I couldn't figure out how to do this with either lubridate or base R dates. I saw one Stackoverflow reply used between() but that didn't seem to work for me at least with lubridate intervals or dateDiff objects. I was also thinking of a lookup function but couldn't figure out how to use that with dates either.
Thanks!

Are you looking for difftime(time1, time2, unit = "weeks")? How can one know that these days, 5/1/YYYY - 9/1/YYYY, are the only relevant ones?

And remember that you are talking to an international audience. Is 5/1/2020 the fifth of January or the first of May?

Here is an example. Consider you have a data.frame with travellers and their start and end dates called dat. And a second data.frame with time periods you would like to consider in your counting (periods)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(
  id = 'traveler1',
  startdate = mdy("3/11/2020"),
  enddate = mdy("7/1/2023")
)

periods <- data.frame(
  period_start = mdy("5/1/2020", "5/1/2021", "5/1/2022", "5/1/2023"),
  period_end = mdy("9/1/2020", "9/1/2021", "9/1/2022", "9/1/2023")
)

Now, we can join these tables together, looking for overlaps in the periods and travel dates. Then, using min and max logic we can easily count the number of days falling within each period. Finally we sum over the different periods to get a single count per traveller.
left_join(
  dat,
  periods,
  join_by(overlaps(startdate, enddate, period_start, period_end))
) |> 
  mutate(day_count = pmin(enddate, period_end) - pmax(startdate, period_start)) |> 
  summarise(day_count = sum(day_count), .by = c(id, startdate, enddate))

Result:
         id  startdate    enddate day_count
1 traveler1 2020-03-11 2023-07-01  430 days


Wonderful, @Axeman, that answers my question perfectly, thanks! The solution is above my current skill in R, but I worked through your solution and looked up the overlaps, pmin, and pmhx function and understand how it works.
I did also discover the "timeDate" pkg which does allow users to make a timeSequence of which I figured out I could then "cut" or select out dates and count eh leftover dates but your solution seems much more efficient.
I apologize to the initial repliers and will be sure in the future to specify what date format I am referring to.

More clarity in the question is always better, but obviously it was clear enough for me to understand!
